# Android kitkat is there possible to delete sent SMS using ContentResolver, if user doesn't select my app as default msging app

Tags: android, security, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to delete the sent sSMS in kitkat and above versions. The only thing that worrying me is "What if user doesn't selects my app as a default messaging app?" Because displaying SMS will be a security threats. Is there any approach which I can try?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. Only the default app has the right to do this.